# Nginx conflicting demands for host header

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to expose one part of my web server via one address, and another part via another. I feel like my use case should be simple, but nginx is giving me a lot of troubles.

What I currently have is this:

Server one:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name mydomain.com;

  location /dev/subfolder {
    proxy_pass http://dev.mydomain.local/subfolder;
    proxy_redirect http:// https://;
  }
}
```

Server two:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name dev.mydomain.com;

  location /main {
    #some config
  }
  location /subfolder {
    return 404;
  }
}
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name dev.mydomain.local;

  location /subfolder {
    #some config
  }
}
```

The problem is, if I add a `proxy_set_header Host $host` directive to server one, the first server block on server two will pick up the request, and return 404. If I don't include that header, my browser will try to navigate to `dev.mydomain.local` and fail, because that domain is only available internally. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: sounds like when it hits dev.mydomain.local its returning like a 301/302 redirect.. can you run something like `curl -v mydomain.com` and paste the results from the same machine as your browser?

Comment: @Mike Sure, here you go: http://pastebin.com/kkw4ac6V

Comment: so now you can run `curl -v mydomain.com/dev/subfolder/`

Comment: Post your full configuration on both servers.